# Wifi light doesnt turn off on Acer Aspire One

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-netbook, acer, aspire-one

I recently installed Ubuntu netbook edition on my Acer Aspire One D255 netbook, and I notice that the wifi light never turns off, even if I'm not connected to a network. When I am connected to a network, it never stops blinking. I dont remember this behaviour when Windows 7 was on it.

Is there a way to turn this light off? Does this mean the wifi is constantly on even when not being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an aspire one as well, and I have noticed that the light remains on (Windows or Linux [**NB** Windows XP]) whether or not I am connected to a network (though it flashes sometimes when I'm downloading anything.

As far as I've been able to tell, the network light is only on if your wireless device is powered (This is how it's supposed to operate btw), and does not remain on if you have the wifi disabled (powered off state).

Don't worry about it, your system is fine (unless I'm missing something). If you want to turn the light off when you are not using a network (and if you want to save some serious power), turn off the wireless switch when you are not using wifi.